# select one character on a component angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to select only one character on a textbox, I'm using angularjs for developing but I need when someone click on the textbox only one character can be selected at time, basically at the beginnig the textbox will have only this simbol '-' everywhere, so the idea is the user can replace only the '-' he needs for other character, does anyone know how? or maybe if some other component on html should be used?

here i leave a little example of how the textbox will be when the applicantion starts

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

now when you click on it I need only can  be possible select one by one, not more tan one ,

I really need thsi, thanks!!

Comment: I still don't get your question about 'select character on a component'. btw to limit only 1 character on input tag html you could use length attribute. ex: <input type="text" length=1>

Comment: are you trying to mimic the Insert Toggle on your keyboard? so that it looks like the the characters are overwriting the text field?